# Show the result of a filter in another sheet, recursively

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a some sheets which names are dates: "2019-01-01" , "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", etc.

In each of them I have this colums

```
A           B        C        D
value       count1   count2   count3
A
A
B
C
A
```

So I want to filter the rows with A cases, like this:

```
filter(A:D,A:A="A")
```

But I want to show this information in another sheet:

```
The result of the filter of the sheet "2019-01-01" should be showed in 
"2019-01-02" 

The result of the filter of the sheet "2019-01-02" should be showed in 
"2019-01-03", etc
```

All these sheets are created from a Template sheet.

How Can I achieve this goal?

Comment: not rly sure what exactly do you want. can you explain it a bit more? so far I understood that you want to show text message if filter formula matches the sheet's name and outputs results. is that correct?